# Trying to find a good example to create a html button in django to run a python function and display result

Tags: python, django, ajax

I've trying for a while now to learn django mostly for my own curiosity. My current goal is to have an button on screen that when pressed does some simple python function at first. Something like display a string value or a random number on the screen. I've found some examples but they're not helping my understanding of the problem. Most examples have been building like buttons or similar.

I've tried looking into ajax calls for python but I can't seem to find writeups that help me with the basics and any video tutorials I find on this topic there is a language barrier which is not helping me learn. Sorry for asking probably a basic question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example of clicking a button in and getting a random number back. I used JQuery, because i find it generally easier and fast- so just take that into account.

Generally when you use Ajax you encode the return data with JSON, so that's what I did.
I used a dictionary, as the JSON return and added my usual keys which are:

1. `status` to return a True/False value to signify if everything went good or not
2. `msg` generic message, mostly for error messages
3. Any extra keys for return data

##### template (html)

```html
{% csrf_token %}
<h3 id="myheader"></h3>
<button id="mybutton">Click Me</button>
```

##### Jquery/Ajax (javascript)

- I provided both a **POST** and a **GET** example.. I generally always use **POST** because I'm sending extra data like: 'give me the Username for person with *This* first name'

```js
// Post Example (If you wanted to send DATA as well)
function ajaxPost(){
    //  if POSTing data, this: {% csrf_token %} must be in the template somewhere
    //                                ^ (it's hidden)
    submitData = {
        'istest': True,
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'myviewurl',
        data: submitData,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            if (data['status']){
                // everything went good
                console.log(data['msg']);
                console.log(data['my_return_data']);

                // do something with returned data
                $('#myheader').html('Returned: ' + data['my_return_data']);

            }else{
                // something went bad
                console.log(data['msg']);
            };
        },
        error: function(event,xhr,settings,errorText){
            console.log('Something Broke')
            // xhr.status , common error table
            // 0    = Server didn't Reply (Server Down)
            // 400  = Bad Request         (Syntax Error)
            // 403  = Forbidden           (Login Token Expired)
            // 403  = Not Found           (Invalid Url)
            // 500  = Server Error        (Django Crash)
        },
    });
};

// GET Example
function ajaxPost(){
    $.ajax({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'myviewurl',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            if (data['status']){
                // everything went good
                console.log(data['msg']);
                console.log(data['my_return_data']);

                // do something with returned data
                $('#myheader').html('Returned: ' + data['my_return_data']);
            }else{
                // something went bad
                console.log(data['msg']);
            };
        },
        error: function(event,xhr,settings,errorText){
            console.log('Something Broke')
        },
    });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mybutton').click(function(){
        // on button click run ajax post

        // run the POST example
        ajaxPost();
    });
});
```

##### view.py

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json

def MyView(request):
    # we just assume it won't work / True = good / false = bad
    returnData = {'status':False}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get Data from post
        testbool = request.POST.get('istest')

        if testbool:
            # do python things

            from random import randrange
            data['my_return_data'] = randrange(10)

            data['status'] = True # everything worked!
            data['msg'] = 'Ran Python Code With a POST!'
        else:
            data['msg'] = 'istest needs to be True'

    else:
        # a GET

        # Do some python stuff
        from random import randrange
        data['my_return_data'] = randrange(10)

        data['status'] = True # everything worked!
        data['msg'] = 'Ran Python Code With a GET!'

    # Return the Data in Json so Javascript can easily use it
    return HttpResponse(
        json.dumps(data),
        content_type="application/json"
    )
```

**Quick Note about JSON** Some things can't be put into Json, like Django Decimal fields.. so you need to transform them into a Json acceptable type- like for the Decimal example you just make it a Float
Any questions, let me know.. Honestly it's best to just play around with it and you'll get the feel

Comment: Thanks for the reply, where would Jquery/ajax code go in the structure? I'm still learning my way around everything as far as where everything needs to go for proper function.

Comment: @AttemptingToLearn to start off you can just place the JavaScript in a `<script>` tag in the HTML.. and then later on you’d put it into an external JavaScript file- or that’s what I do, the eventual goal is to have it in its own .js file